# Lightbox gallery is not working in mobile website

Tags: javascript

I am using D7 and lightbox2 for image gallery.

I'm using same in the mobile version too. But the lightbox popup is not opening and showing in mobile browsers. It will work sometimes and will never work on another occasion. What is the reason of this issue?

Using `Lightbox2: lightshow:thumbnail->original`  in content filed display, I used other options, but showed the same issue.

After that is used colorbox, it's working ok but when we close the popup window the parent window is blank and showing the same error `undefined`

> undefined

Also the page url is changed to the image url. E.g., 
`www.site.com/sites/default/files/DSC_0164.jpg`

**Mobile jQuery 7.x-2.0-beta1 (default mobile theme by Mobile Switch)**

How can I overcome this issue? How can I open image in modal window. It was working perfectly before, now it's showing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

At last I found an alternative solution for image gallery:

Photoswipe,it is working for me...(Compatible with lots of mobile devices and all popular JavaScript libraries and development frameworks. )

```
http://www.photoswipe.com/
```

sample:

```
http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/04-jquery-mobile.html
```